# Ignoring 'Content-type: application/pdf' and setting to 'Content-type: application/octet-stream

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I have some php code code

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
readfile($tempfile);
```

The file downloads fine but when I query the mime type it returns `_application/octet-stream_`

Comment: Query the MIME type from what?

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean with what? I used xdg-mime query filetype

Comment: What's the filename? Is this IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xdg-mime is "command line tool for querying information about file type handling and adding descriptions for new file types"

This suggests that you are downloading the file (generated via PHP), saving it to disk, and then examining the saved file with the tool.

The tool has no way of knowing what the HTTP response said. It only has access to the saved file.

While the Content-Type says "This is a PDF file" it doesn't turn the file into a PDF or change the ability of tools that do not examine the HTTP header to identify what type the file is.

Comment: The file I was downloading had a problem. Thanks!